# scale image only width with minimagick in ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick, minimagick

I am using this method for resize the images:

```
version :big do
            process :resize_to_fit => [560, 200]
            process :convert => :png
          end
```

But with this method I have that write a height fixed.

I want only scale or resize the width image.

I want the height of the image is automatic and scale the image to the width that has been given.

How can I scale or resize, only the width image?

**I'm using [minimagick with carrierwave](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/CarrierWave/MiniMagick.html).**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to do this. Here's an example:

```
  version :column do
    process :resize_to_fit => [250, nil]
  end
```

This version will be rescaled so that the width is the specified value (250, in my case), and will retain the aspect ratio.